# ReactJS - Target random element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some problems understanding how you interact with element in React after rendering. I currently got this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y7dh3vh5/

```
var items = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola"....

var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function() {
       return { items: [] }
    },
    render: function() {
        var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item, i) {
            return (
                <div className="item" key={i}>
                   <p>{item}</p>
                </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div>
               {listItems}
            </div>
        );
    }});ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={items} />, document.getElementById('itemList'));
```

And I'm looking for a way to highlight a random country when I press the "Highlight random country"-button. Is there an easy way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add state to save highlightedIndex:

```
getInitialState () {
    return {
        highlightedIndex: -1
    }
},
```

Add method for button

```
setNewTarget: function() {
    var l = this.props.items.length - 1;
    this.setState({
        highlightedIndex: this.randomInteger(0, l)
    })
},
```

Put button into return render

```
return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.setNewTarget}>
            Highlight random country
        </button>
        {listItems}
    </div>
);
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ufmagg4o/

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your index element in state and compare it in `map` method. I prefere es6 so i hope you will understand

```
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
    this.state = {
      items: ['hello', 'world', 'random', 'highlight'],
      index: null
    }
    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
  }
  click(){
    const items = this.state.items;
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
    this.setState({index: index})
  }
  render(){
    const list = this.state.items.map((item,index)=>{
        return <p key={index} className={this.state.index === index ? 'item': null}>
          {item}
        </p>
    })
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.click}>Click me</button>
      {list}
    </div>
  }
}

React.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[`fiddle example`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/362/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The key is to keep that button inside React. Don't try to manipulate React components from outside React.

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>
<div id="itemList">
</div>
```

```css
.highlighted {
  color: white;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```js
var items = [
        "Afghanistan",
        "Albania",
        "Algeria",
        "Andorra",
        "Angola"
]; // etc...


var RepeatModule = React.createClass({
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return { items: [] }
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {highlighted: null};
  },
  onClickButton() {
    this.setState({
      highlighted: (Math.random() * this.props.items.length)|0
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var _this = this;
    var listItems = this.props.items.map(function(item, i) {
      return (
        <div className="item" key={i}>
          <p className={i == _this.state.highlighted ? 'highlighted' : null}>
            {item}
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClickButton}>
          Highlight random country
        </button>
        <div>
          {listItems}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={items} />, document.getElementById('itemList'));
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9503j5y5/)

ES2015 version:

```js
const items = [
        "Afghanistan",
        "Albania",
        "Algeria",
        "Andorra",
        "Angola"
]; // etc...


class RepeatModule extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {items: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string)};
  static defaultProps = {items: []};
  state = { highlighted: null };
  onClickButton = () => {
    this.setState({
      highlighted: (Math.random() * this.props.items.length)|0
    });
  };
  render() {
    const listItems = this.props.items.map((item, i) => (
      <div className="item" key={i}>
        <p className={i == this.state.highlighted ? 'highlighted' : null}>
          {item}
        </p>
      </div>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClickButton}>
          Highlight random country
        </button>
        <div>
          {listItems}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<RepeatModule items={items} />, document.getElementById('itemList'));
```